# USE Jpa Where with a list := Key

Tags: java, jpa

I would like do an SQL JPA query with a list object but when I try I have this error message:

> Cannot be resolved to a valid type.

I use JPA with maven. I would like do this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Personne")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByKeyClient", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.keyClient = :keyClient"),
     @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.CountPersonne", query = "SELECT COUNT(p) FROM Personne p WHERE p.sessionCollection.keySession = :keySession "),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByNom", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.nom = :nom"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByPrenom", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.prenom = :prenom"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByEmail", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.email = :email"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByTelephone", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.telephone = :telephone"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByPortable", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.portable = :portable"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByFax", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.fax = :fax"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByDateModification", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.dateModification = :dateModification"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByDateCreation", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.dateCreation = :dateCreation"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByActif", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.actif = :actif")})
public class Personne implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "KeyClient")
    private String keyClient;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Nom")
    private String nom;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Prenom")
    private String prenom;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Email")
    private String email;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Telephone")
    private String telephone;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Portable")
    private String portable;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "TypeInscription")
    private String typeInscription;
    // @Pattern(regexp="^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$", message="Invalid phone/fax format, should be as xxx-xxx-xxxx")//if the field contains phone or fax number consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Fax")
    private String fax;
    @Column(name = "DateModification")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateModification;
    @Column(name = "DateCreation")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateCreation;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "KeyTypeUser")
    private TypeUser typeUser;
    @Size(max = 1)
    @Column(name = "actif")
    private String actif;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "KeyEntreprise")
    private Entreprise entreprise;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "KeyCivilite")
    private Civilite civilite;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personne",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Login> loginCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personne",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<SourceInscription> sourceInscriptionCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personne",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<CorrespondanceImportation> CorrespondanceImportationCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personne",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Hotesse> hotesseCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personne",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Passage> passageCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personne",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Produit> produitCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personne",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Droit> droitCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personne",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ReponseClient> reponseClientCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "utilisateurSource",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<SourceInscription> PersonneUtilisateurSourceCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personne",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<AutreInformation> autreInformationCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personne",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<CrmLien> CrmLienCollection;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Session> sessionCollection;

    public Personne() {
    }

    public Personne(String keyClient) {
        this.keyClient = keyClient;
    }

    public String getKeyClient() {
        return keyClient;
    }

    public void setKeyClient(String keyClient) {
        this.keyClient = keyClient;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public String getTypeInscription() {
        return typeInscription;
    }

    public void setTypeInscription(String typeInscription) {
        this.typeInscription = typeInscription;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public String getPortable() {
        return portable;
    }

    public void setPortable(String portable) {
        this.portable = portable;
    }

    public String getFax() {
        return fax;
    }

    public void setFax(String fax) {
        this.fax = fax;
    }

    public Date getDateModification() {
        return dateModification;
    }

    public void setDateModification(Date dateModification) {
        this.dateModification = dateModification;
    }

    public Date getDateCreation() {
        return dateCreation;
    }

    public void setDateCreation(Date dateCreation) {
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
    }

    public String getActif() {
        return actif;
    }

    public void setActif(String actif) {
        this.actif = actif;
    }

    public TypeUser getTypeUser() {
        return typeUser;
    }

    public void setTypeUser(TypeUser typeUser) {
        this.typeUser = typeUser;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public List<Login> getLoginCollection() {
        return loginCollection;
    }

    public void setLoginCollection(List<Login> loginCollection) {
        this.loginCollection = loginCollection;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public List<CrmLien> getCrmLienCollection() {
        return CrmLienCollection;
    }

    public void setCrmLienCollection(List<CrmLien> CrmLienCollection) {
        this.CrmLienCollection = CrmLienCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<SourceInscription> getSourceInscriptionCollection() {
        return sourceInscriptionCollection;
    }

    public void setSourceInscriptionCollection(List<SourceInscription> sourceInscriptionCollection) {
        this.sourceInscriptionCollection = sourceInscriptionCollection;
    }

    public Entreprise getEntreprise() {
        return entreprise;
    }

    public void setEntreprise(Entreprise entreprise) {
        this.entreprise = entreprise;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public List<CorrespondanceImportation> getCorrespondanceImportationCollection() {
        return CorrespondanceImportationCollection;
    }

    public void setCorrespondanceImportationCollection(List<CorrespondanceImportation> CorrespondanceImportationCollection) {
        this.CorrespondanceImportationCollection = CorrespondanceImportationCollection;
    }

    public Civilite getCivilite() {
        return civilite;
    }

    public void setCivilite(Civilite civilite) {
        this.civilite = civilite;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public List<Hotesse> getHotesseCollection() {
        return hotesseCollection;
    }

    public void setHotesseCollection(List<Hotesse> hotesseCollection) {
        this.hotesseCollection = hotesseCollection;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public List<Passage> getPassageCollection() {
        return passageCollection;
    }

    public void setPassageCollection(List<Passage> passageCollection) {
        this.passageCollection = passageCollection;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public List<SourceInscription> getPersonneUtilisateurSourceCollection() {
        return PersonneUtilisateurSourceCollection;
    }

    public void setPersonneUtilisateurSourceCollection(List<SourceInscription> PersonneUtilisateurSourceCollection) {
        this.PersonneUtilisateurSourceCollection = PersonneUtilisateurSourceCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Produit> getProduitCollection() {
        return produitCollection;
    }

    public void setProduitCollection(List<Produit> produitCollection) {
        this.produitCollection = produitCollection;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public List<Droit> getDroitCollection() {
        return droitCollection;
    }

    public void setDroitCollection(List<Droit> droitCollection) {
        this.droitCollection = droitCollection;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public List<ReponseClient> getReponseClientCollection() {
        return reponseClientCollection;
    }

    public void setReponseClientCollection(List<ReponseClient> reponseClientCollection) {
        this.reponseClientCollection = reponseClientCollection;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public List<AutreInformation> getAutreInformationCollection() {
        return autreInformationCollection;
    }

    public void setAutreInformationCollection(List<AutreInformation> autreInformationCollection) {
        this.autreInformationCollection = autreInformationCollection;
    }
    @XmlTransient
     public List<Session> getSessionCollection() {
        return sessionCollection;
    }

    public void setSessionCollection(List<Session> sessionCollection) {
        this.sessionCollection = sessionCollection;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (keyClient != null ? keyClient.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Personne)) {
            return false;
        }
        Personne other = (Personne) object;
        if ((this.keyClient == null && other.keyClient != null) || (this.keyClient != null && !this.keyClient.equals(other.keyClient))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "fr.ietevents.client.Entity.Personne[ keyClient=" + keyClient + " ]";
    }

}
```

Session entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Session")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Session.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Session s"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Session.findByKeyEdition", query = "SELECT s FROM Session s WHERE s.keySession = :keySession"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Session.findByNom", query = "SELECT s FROM Session s WHERE s.nom = :nom")})
public class Session implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "KeySession")
    private String keySession;
    @Size(max = 90)
    @Column(name = "Nom")
    private String nom;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "KeyAdresse")
    private Adresse adresse ;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "session",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Passage> passageCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "session",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Droit> droitCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "session",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Question> questionCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "session",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Css> cssCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "session",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Site> siteCollection;
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "session",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<CrmLien> crmLienCollection;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="sessionCollection",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Personne> personneCollection;

    public Session() {
    }
    public Session(String keySession) {
        this.keySession = keySession;
    }

    public String getKeySession() {
        return keySession;
    }

    public void setKeySession(String keyEdition) {
        this.keySession = keyEdition;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public Adresse getAdresse() {
        return adresse;
    }

    public void setAdresse(Adresse adresse) {
        this.adresse = adresse;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public List<CrmLien> getCrmLienCollection() {
        return crmLienCollection;
    }

    public void setCrmLienCollection(List<CrmLien> crmLienCollection) {
        this.crmLienCollection = crmLienCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Passage> getPassageCollection() {
        return passageCollection;
    }

    public void setPassageCollection(List<Passage> passageCollection) {
        this.passageCollection = passageCollection;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public List<Droit> getDroitCollection() {
        return droitCollection;
    }

    public void setDroitCollection(List<Droit> droitCollection) {
        this.droitCollection = droitCollection;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public List<Question> getQuestionCollection() {
        return questionCollection;
    }

    public void setQuestionCollection(List<Question> questionCollection) {
        this.questionCollection = questionCollection;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public List<Css> getCssCollection() {
        return cssCollection;
    }

    public void setCssCollection(List<Css> CssCollection) {
        this.cssCollection = CssCollection;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public List<Site> getSiteCollection() {
        return siteCollection;
    }

    public void setSiteCollection(List<Site> siteCollection) {
        this.siteCollection = siteCollection;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public List<Personne> getPersonneCollection() {
        return personneCollection;
    }

    public void setPersonneCollection(List<Personne> personneCollection) {
        this.personneCollection = personneCollection;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (keySession != null ? keySession.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Session)) {
            return false;
        }
        Session other = (Session) object;
        if ((this.keySession == null && other.keySession != null) || (this.keySession != null && !this.keySession.equals(other.keySession))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "fr.ietevents.client.Entity.Session[ keyEdition=" + keySession + " ]";
    }

}
```

I have Collection session is a list of Object Session.

```
public Long CountPersonne(Session  session,Pays pays){
      EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
      try{
          Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Personne.CountPersonne");
          query.setParameter("keySession",session.getKeySession());
        //  query.setParameter("keyPays",pays.getKeyPays());
         return (Long) query.getSingleResult();

      }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e);
          return 0l;
      }finally{
             em.close();

        }
  }
```

error message :

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [fr.ietevents_Client_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT COUNT(p) FROM Personne p WHERE p.sessionCollection.keySession = :keySession ]. 
[38, 68] The state field path 'p.sessionCollection.keySession' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createDeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:820)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:760)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:182)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:527)
    org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:140)
    org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    fr.ietevents.client.Facades.SessionFacade.getEntityManager(SessionFacade.java:27)
    fr.ietevents.client.Facades.AbstractFacade.find(AbstractFacade.java:96)
    fr.ietevents.client.MyResource.getIt(MyResource.java:395)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Comment: Please share the code that is giving you the error.

Comment: i add the code that is giving my error

Comment: no you haven't. You need to post entity "Personne" (so people can SEE what is "CollectionEntreprise"). Also any exception has a stack trace, which also needs including

Comment: i have add entity Personne

Comment: Still need the stack trace and the full error message.  What can't be resolved to a valid type?  What is the session.getKeySession() you are passing in?  Try using e.printStackTrace() in your catch block.

Comment: i have add a error message

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use

```
p.sessionCollection.keySession
```

in JPQL, since there is a multivalued field there. You need to form the JOIN in the query yourself, like this

```
SELECT COUNT(p) FROM Personne p JOIN p.sessionCollection sc WHERE sc.keySession = :keySession
```